# Salesforce SSO Org Id appending username intermittently

Tags: salesforce1-app, authentication, saml

How do I stop sending the Org id and just the username?

But this is happening intermittently.

Comment: please provide more details

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identity_provider_portals_sites.htm&type=5):

When defining a service provider, if the Subject Type is Username, the Salesforce organization ID is prepended to the user name in the SAML assertion. For example, if the user is jDeoint@WFC.com, the subject for the SAML assertion contains 00DE0000000FFLT@jDeoint@WFC.com.

If the Subject Type is Federation ID, the exact federation ID is used.

If you don't want this to be returned in your SAML response, you should change the Subject Type to one of the available options. To view the available options, refer to [Defining Service Providers as SAML-Enabled Connected Apps](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=service_provider_define.htm&type=5).

**Subject Type**

Specifies which field defines the user’s identity for the app. Options include the user’s username, federation ID, user ID, a custom attribute, or an algorithmically calculated persistent ID. A custom attribute can be any custom field added to the User object in the organization, as long as it is one of the following data types: Email, Text, URL, or Formula (with Text Return Type). After you select Custom Attribute for the Subject Type, Salesforce displays a Custom Attribute field with a list of the available User object custom fields in the organization.

Try this.